# How insert Marathi using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using php and MySQL for my project

I want to store Marathi text in the MySQL database, I googled for hours and found a half of a solution by changing the MySQL database encoding to utf-8. I can manually (through PHPMyAdmin)store Marathi characters in Mysql database.

But, when I try to insert some text using php, I get "???"(Question marks) instead of Marathi characters.

Do I need to set encoding in php also? If so then how?

Here's the code to insert data in the database

```
public function create_place(){  
    include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/_inc.php' );
      $q = $_REQUEST;
        $person_id=$q['person_id'];
        $title = $q['title'];
        $address = $q['address'];
        $mobile=$q['mobile'];
        $latitude=$q['latitude'];
        $longitude=$q['longitude'];
        $cat_id=$q['cat_id'];
        $create_time=Date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
        $sql="INSERT INTO place(person_id,title,address,mobile,latitude,longitude,cat_id,create_time) VALUE('$person_id','$title','$address','$mobile','$latitude','$longitude','$cat_id','$create_time')";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        $lastid = $this->db->insert_id();
         //echo $lastid;
            include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ). '/SimpleImage.php' );
            $_REQUEST['id'] = $lastid;
            include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ). '/SimpleImage.php' );
            include_once( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/_inc.php' );
            $target= FCPATH. '/assets/uploads/place/';
            $target1=$target.basename(date('m-d-Y_H:i:s').'_'.$_REQUEST['id'].'_'.@$_FILES['image']['name']);
            $img=basename(date('m-d-Y_H:i:s').'_'.$_REQUEST['id'].'_'.@$_FILES['image']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target1);
            $this->load->model( 'mplace' );
            $sql="UPDATE place set image='$img' WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";
            $this->db->query($sql);
        $this->_render_json( array(
            'message' => 'place Create Successfully',
            'image'=>$this->image_url('place',$img),
        ) );

        $this->_render_json( $data );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not configured your code properly. You are getting `???` because you are not telling your browser how to parse Marathi. Add this piece of code to your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then, check whether the column you are storing Marathi in has the collation type `utf8_general_ci` . To do so, the SQL command `SHOW TABLE STATUS` should display your table's properties. If the collation is not `utf8_general_ci` then change it by the following SQL Command:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MarathiTable 
MODIFY marathi varchar(100)COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Make sure that your insert statements are appropriately configured as follows:

```
"INSERT INTO `comments`(id,comment) values (N'$id',N'$comment')";
```

Here, the prefix `N` tells the SQL engine that it the inserted values are of a national regional language character set.

Also, write this at the beginning of your program to set all important variables to `utf8`. You can thus perform all other operations without worrying about encoding.

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this before your query `mysql_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');` or `mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');`

In database structure keep its collation to `utf8_general_ci`

This will solve your issue.